# Stream if not null and get the first object

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, method-reference

I am trying to apply stream on a list which can be `null` as it is calling a repository method and I want to get the first element from it if it is not null and compare one of its parameter with request value.

```
Optional.ofNullable(placementRepository.findAllByAccountId(accountId))
            .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
            .stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .findFirst()
            .get()
            .getPlacementDate()
            .isAfter(placementRequest.getPlacementDate())
```

Currently it is failing at `.get` if the list itself is `null` though I filtered with nonNull. I want stream the list if the list is not null and get the first element and compare its parameter against other value. I tried with other alternative filters but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want stream the list if the list is not null and get the first
>   element and compare its parameter against other value.

You didn't think of the case of empty or null elements in the returned List of the repository. You have to choose a default value or execute the date comparison only if the optional is present.

For example with a default date value :

```
final LocalDate defaultDateValue = ...;

 Optional.ofNullable(placementRepository.findAllByAccountId(accountId))
         .flatMapping(l -> l.stream()
                            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                            .findFirst()
                            .mapping(o -> o.getPlacementDate())
          )
         .orElse(defaultDateValue)
         .isAfter(placementRequest.getPlacementDate())
```

With a conditional processing :

```
Optional<LocalDate> opt = 
    Optional.ofNullable(placementRepository.findAllByAccountId(accountId))
            .flatMapping(l -> l.stream()
                               .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                               .findFirst()
                               .mapping(o -> o.getPlacementDate())
             )

if (opt.isPresent()){          
     boolean isAfter = opt.get().isAfter(placementRequest.getPlacementDate());    
     // ...
 }
```

Comment: I have seen the second approach but was trying to fit everything in a single statement. If I have provide default value then I should be looking at the second approach only but thought people may question me at work if there is a better way. Any I choose to go with second approach and see

Comment: It is not a question of code quality/fluency. Here you want to compare an hypothetical date (because you are not sure to find it) to another data. So you cannot do it with a single statement without default value for the not found date or for the final boolean result.

Answer (score 1):

`Optional<T> findFirst();`, so in case you have `null` or `empty` stream, then this method returns `null`.

You should use `.findFirst().orElseGet(() -> /* NULL object*/)`

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `.findFirst()` is able to return no result at all and `.get()` will fail. You can use `.ifPresent()` or use `.orElseGet()`

Answer (score 0):

Considering the type of elements in your list is `YourPojo`, this code snippet should do what you need:

```
List<YourPojo> list = placementRepository.findAllByAccountId(accountId); 
LocalDate date = placementRequest.getPlacementDate();

boolean flag =
    Optional.ofNullable(list)                 // Optional<List<YourPojo>>
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)      // Stream<YourPojo>
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)         // Stream<YourPojo>
            .findFirst()                      // Optional<YourPojo>
            .map(YourPojo::getPlacementDate)  // Optional<LocalDate>
            .map(d -> d.isAfter(date))        // Optional<Boolean>
            .orElse(false);                   // Boolean
```

*Note: If you're using Java 11 or above then `.map(d -> d.isAfter(date))` can be replaced by `.map(not(date::isBefore))`. Not sure if it's more readable though.*